# PHP - Namespaces - Import

Tags: php, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing variable namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404374/importing-variable-namespaces)

Having some issues with namespaces i cannot seem to resolve.
Tried to look up google on it but does not really give me a correct approach.

The this is that i got a string. This string is then a namespace i need to import.
Here is a example of what i am trying to do.

```
$test = "test";
use obj/$test/con
```

The namespace obj/test/con exists and have a class in it.

But when using those 2 lines of code i get a white page.

-

New to namespaces for PHP and this errors is kinda getting me stuck :)

Hope some of you can help. Appreciate all attempts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404374/importing-variable-namespaces), you cannot use a variable in a "use" statement. What is it that you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Thank you. That link was the answer i was looking for. Archived it by using a new '//path//some//class'  :)